# ASP.NET AjaxControlToolkit CascadingDropdown suspend autopostback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autopostback

Using the [ASP.NET AjaxControltoolkit CascadingDropDown](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CascadingDropDown&referringTitle=Reference) (v15.1.4) , I have multiple dropdowns (two for the sake of simplicity for this question)

```
<!-- Top Level -->
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="drp_level1" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>

<!-- Second Level -->
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="drp_level2" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="casc_l2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Category="x" ParentControlID="drp_level1" TargetControlID="drp_level2" ServicePath="~/method.asmx" ServiceMethod="x" />
```

The problem with this approach is that the cascading dropdown is updating the contents of level 2 (correctly), but then that is triggering another postback (which reloads the page, and then the cascade re-runs, triggering another postback and so on.

**Update for clarity:** The dropdowns are both being used as filters ...

- The page would initially display a list of unfiltered data
- Dropdown 1 would perhaps contain a list of continents
- Dropdown 2 would perhaps contain a list of countries (dependent on the level1 choice)
- Dropdowns 3 and beyond would perhaps display other things (dependent on the continent)
- Each dropdown could be selected individually to filter the data further [instant postback causing a data-refresh], but the contents of dropdowns 2 and beyond will depend on the "grouping" chosen in level1.

**What I have tried (unsuccessfully)**

```
<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  Sys.Application.add_load(initializePage);

  function initializePage() {
    $find('casc_l2').add_populating(stop_auto);
    $find('casc_l2').add_populated(start_auto);
  }

  function stop_auto(sender, e) {
    $find('drp_level2').set_autopostback(false);
  }
  function start_auto(sender, e) {
    $find('drp_level2').set_autopostback(true);
  }
</script>
```

**Workaround** :- I could disable the auto-postback and force the user to manually click a button to re-submit .. but this is messy.

What I would like is for the "user-selection" of the dropdown to cause a postback, but for the "cascaded-refill" of the dropdown not to.

Comment: Can you show sample data in the first DropDown and ServiceMethod implementation? Also, do you select data in the second combobox after page load or select something in the first combobox before it?